# Security role to user/group mapping: Error ADMA0014E: No virtual host specified

Tags: websphere, virtualhost, websphere-8, virtual-hosts

When trying to save via OK Button, I'm getting this error and WebSphere is not saving it. How can I fix that?

[image]

EDIT: This is the error message I'm trying to resolve with the configuration in WebSphere:

```
[6/20/16 10:46:34:524 CEST] 00000034 WebCollaborat A   SECJ0129E: Authorization failed for user TUZRS01:customRealm while invoking GET on null:/TestProject/, Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles: User
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21643203

Comment: This is strange. I'd suggest removing application from the server, restarting the server and adding application again.

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

@DYangu's link to [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21643203) pointed me in the right direction. When installing via wsadmin, it appears that the `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file is created automatically. If trying to install the application from eclipse/RAD, however, the file is not created.

What I did to resolve was create the above named file in my web application project (war) under WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <virtual-host name="default_host"/>
</web-bnd>
```

After doing this, I was able to successfully map the security role to the module.

Comment: Just a note: the article mention `ibm-web-bnd.xmi` and not `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. My war files had the following two files missing inside war/WEB-INF folder

- ibm-web-bnd.xml
- ibm-web-ext.xml

Using the option of Generate Default Binding while installing WAR solved the issue for me.
[image: Generate Default Binding]